# Show Passwords feature in Ultimate Membership pro Forms

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, plugins

How can I add show password field in my forms?
I try this code in my function but didn't work
add_filter("um_confirm_user_password_form_edit_field","um_user_password_form_edit_field", 10, 2 );
add_filter("um_user_password_form_edit_field","um_user_password_form_edit_field", 10, 2 );
function um_user_password_form_edit_field( $output, $set_mode ){

```
ob_start();
 ?>
<div id='um-field-show-passwords-<?php echo $set_mode;?>' style='text-align:right;display:block;'>
    <i class='um-faicon-eye-slash'></i>
    <a href='#'><?php _e("Show password","ultimate-member"); ?></a>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery('div[id="um-field-show-passwords-<?php echo $set_mode;?>"] a').click(function(){ 
     
        var $parent = jQuery(this).parent("div"); 
        var $form = jQuery(".um-<?php echo $set_mode;?> .um-form");

        $parent.find("i").toggleClass(function() {
            if ( jQuery( this ).hasClass( "um-faicon-eye-slash" ) ) {
                $parent.find("a").text('<?php _e("Hide password","ultimate-member"); ?>');
                jQuery( this ).removeClass( "um-faicon-eye-slash" )
                $form.find(".um-field-password").find("input[type=password]").attr("type","text");
               return "um-faicon-eye";
            }
             
            jQuery( this ).removeClass( "um-faicon-eye" );
            $parent.find("a").text('<?php _e("Show password","ultimate-member"); ?>');
            $form.find(".um-field-password").find("input[type=text]").attr("type","password");
          
            return "um-faicon-eye-slash";
        });

        return false; 

    });
</script>
<?php 
return $output.ob_get_clean();
```

}

Comment: Can you explain what happens? 
Your toggleClass logic seems to be fine. Can you create a reproducible example as a codesanbox? replace the PHP values with what they resolve to!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
add_filter( "um_confirm_user_password_form_edit_field", "um_user_password_form_edit_field", 10, 2 );
add_filter( "um_user_password_form_edit_field", "um_user_password_form_edit_field", 10, 2 );

function um_user_password_form_edit_field( $output, $set_mode ) {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div id='um-field-show-passwords-<?php echo $set_mode; ?>' style='text-align:right;display:block;'>
        <i class='um-faicon-eye-slash'></i>
        <a href='#'><?php _e( "Show password", "ultimate-member" ); ?></a>
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
            $( 'body' ).on( 'click', 'div#um-field-show-passwords-<?php echo $set_mode; ?> a', function() {
                var $parent = $( this ).parent( 'div' );
                var $form = $( '.um-<?php echo $set_mode; ?> .um-form' );

                $parent.find( 'i' ).toggleClass( function() {
                    if ( $( this ).hasClass( 'um-faicon-eye-slash' ) ) {
                        $parent.find( 'a' ).text( '<?php _e( "Hide password", "ultimate-member" ); ?>' );
                        $( this ).removeClass( 'um-faicon-eye-slash' )
                        $form.find( '.um-field-password' ).find( 'input[type=password]' ).attr( 'type', 'text' );
                        return 'um-faicon-eye';
                    }
                    $( this ).removeClass( 'um-faicon-eye' );
                    $parent.find( 'a' ).text( '<?php _e( "Show password", "ultimate-member" ); ?>' );
                    $form.find( '.um-field-password' ).find( 'input[type=text]' ).attr( 'type', 'password' );
                    return 'um-faicon-eye-slash';
                } );

                return false;
            } );
        } );
    </script>
    <?php
    return $output . ob_get_clean();
}
```

The code is intended to add a "Show password" functionality to a password field in a form generated by the Ultimate Member plugin in WordPress. Here's a breakdown of what the code does:

Two filter hooks, "um_confirm_user_password_form_edit_field" and "um_user_password_form_edit_field", are defined and hooked with the "um_user_password_form_edit_field" function. These filter hooks are assumed to be properly defined and hooked in your WordPress theme or plugin.

Inside the "um_user_password_form_edit_field" function, output buffering is started with ob_start() to capture the generated HTML.

A  element with an ID of "um-field-show-passwords" is created, which contains an icon and an anchor link with the text "Show password".

A JavaScript block is included to handle the click event on the "Show password" anchor link. It uses jQuery to target the appropriate DOM elements based on the $set_mode parameter provided by the filter hook.

When the "Show password" link is clicked, the JavaScript code toggles the visibility of the password field by changing its type attribute from "password" to "text" and vice versa. It also updates the text of the anchor link to "Hide password" when the password is shown, and "Show password" when the password is hidden.

The captured HTML output and JavaScript code are then returned to the appropriate location in the form via the $output parameter and ob_get_clean() function.